# How to maintain constant record result when separated by comma using python?

Tags: python

facing some issue with output now. I am reading a file with is of 2199 length and trying to place commas at required positions. in an output I am getting like below, commas are coming into next line. This is happening for few records.

Ex:

```
000XXXXXX,062,035,00,00 <=== First line 
,000C160YYYYY,086,047,00, <=== next line
```

Code is

```
for line in file: 
    string=list(line) 
    commas=[15,18,21,23,25] 
    for i in reversed(commas): 
        string.insert(i, ',') 
    result=''.join(string) 
    outfile.write(result)
```

How can I get the uniform output as expected?:

```
 000XXXXXX,062,035,00,00 <=== First line 
 000C160YYYYY,086,047,00 <=== 2nd line
```

Comment: why dont you just do `if line.startswith(',')`? Also, where did the 3rd line come from?

Comment: Could you put some example inputs and outputs with the same amount of lines.

Comment: Could you also explain the logic behind where you want the commas?

Comment: @Sekhar The question is pretty unclear, can you please edit and provide your sample input

Comment: Input:
aabbccdd
11223344

Expected Output:
aa,bb,cc,dd
11,22,33,44

Actual Output:
aa,bb,cc,dd
,11,22,33,44

for few records, comma is coming before each record

Comment: So are you comma separating each 2 chars? Or every consecutive char which is the same? Your original code and example doesn't imply either of these.

Comment: given an example data. the comma positions are not same. but my concerns is comma is placing for some records. I really dont understand why? I think my logic is wrong. but this logic is working fine for one or two records.

Comment: Regarding the program logic: You are placing some commas after the new line character. They then appear in the next line.

Comment: oh, what should I do to maintain a uniform commas?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that some of your records have a length of `expected_length -1`

You are not stripping the right hand side of the line, `rstrip()` and that means that you insert a comma right after the `\n`. That's why the comma shows up before the next line.

Do something like:

```
for line in file: 
    string=list(line) 
    commas=[15,18,21,23,25] 
    if len(string) < 25:  # you could do a loop to check for lengths under 25
        commas.pop()
    for i in reversed(commas): 
        string.insert(i, ',') 
    result=''.join(string) 
    outfile.write(result)
```

Although it would be much better that you make sure that you know what the expected format is, because you can then write generic code to handle the complete situation.

See the documentation (python 2, but it's the same for Python 3) for `list.insert`

- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

> list.insert(i, x)
>   Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x).

With `string.insert(25, ',')` you are inserting at `len(string)` and therefore appending to the line.